# Repeated nearest-neighbor queries

Tags: trees, nearest-neighbour, voronoi-diagrams

If I want to make N repeated (i.e. millions of) 2D nearest-neighbor queries on a pointset of size M, is traveling down into a KD-Tree most efficient or are there better ways to do this? (e.g. Voronoi?)

Right now I'm building a KD-Tree of size M, so with N queries on that I end up using N log M time. Can I do better?

Comment: Related: [space partitioning DS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_partitioning#Data_structures). I'd also check out [Foundations of Multidimensional and Metric Data Structures](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1076819), probably don't read the entire book unless you're truly interested, but you can see the table of contents on [amazon](http://a.co/cj5cd5E) and maybe get some ideas from there.

Comment: What do you mean by better? Can you tell anything about the data? Are queries bounded somehow? If you could switch to Octrees, you may save a lot in terms of performance, but lose a bit with memory. With proper indexing it may be a hash table with octree at the bottom.

Comment: If $N = \Omega(M^2)$, then you can just build a huge lookup table in $O(M^2)$ time and space that contains the answer for every possible query, and then answer each query in $O(1)$ time.  A second idea: Is it necessary to answer each query before the next one arrives?  If not, it might be possible to get practical (and possibly even theoretical) speedups by answering them in a different order.